# reading a CSV file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, csv

I need to parse and sort data of a very large size CSV file. Please note file is really large of around 600K rows. I don't need to store it some where or import to DB. Please guide what can be efficient way to do this implementation. I appreciate your sharing experience.

Comment: Why do you need to sort if you just need the median value?

Comment: Read [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) to get the whole picture on CSV and then search a library that will handle CSV data according to RFC 4180

Comment: http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Sorting/SortBigFiles/

Comment: Best way is to read numbers into a list object which will reduce size.  The input sting takes up more memory than parsed numbers.  Once you get the total number of values you do not need to sort the entire array to get median.  You only need to do a bubble sort on half the items to get median.

Comment: "cant find median without sorting" -- for in-memory collections you can use [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm

Comment: Many of the CSV libraries like CSVHelper would make this pretty simple and even efficient since you dont need to load all the data

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this...

```
var list = new List<float>(10000);
using (var fs = new StreamReader(new FileStream("file.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 8192, FileOptions.SequentialScan)))
{
    var line = fs.ReadLine();
    var columns = line.Split(',');
    list.Add(Convert.ToSingle(columns[5]));
}
// Sort the list and do your calculations...
```

Notice `FileOptions.SequentialScan`, also play with the `bufferSize` (not sure if the default value is 4096 or 8192) to get better results... Also pre-allocate the list size to prevent resizing of the list...

Comment: Thanks @Michael, can I read just one column ? I will need data from a single column will it effecient to read a column ?

Comment: @user576510 If all columns/column-contents have a fixed width/length, you could position the file-cursor right before the column, read the content, and then jump n-bytes forward to the next rows column. But for normal csv-files i assume variable-length-columns and then the answer is no, since you dont know where your data-column starts and when the current line ends...

Comment: Try parse [this csv](http://imgur.com/a/url59).

Comment: @AleksAndreev I think thats very uncommon and user576510 did not mention that his dataset can contain multi-row-data... But that can also be handled... The first line with the column-names tells you how many columns the dataset has. When reading the content line-by-line you could count the columns and if the number is smaller then expected read the next line and so on... But I think we're a little off-topic here, aren't we?

Comment: @Michael Read [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) Section 2.6

Comment: BTW it is very easy to get around that: Count the occurance of the quote char. A complete data row must contain an even number of quote chars

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle the large file sorting by using external sorting. There are number of CSV libraries offers them out of the box.

[Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) has CSVReader with external sorting capability. You can leverage it for your purpose

a. Define POCO class to represent CSV record. Important: mark the class as serializable to eligible for external sorting.

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    [ChoCSVRecordField(1)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ChoCSVRecordField(2)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [ChoCSVRecordField(4)]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [ChoCSVRecordField(6)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

b. Write comparer class to sort against a column (ex. lets sort by City)

```
public class AddressCityComparer : IComparer<Customer>
{
    public int Compare(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.City, y.City);
    }
}
```

c. Lastly, use ChoCSVReader to load the CSV file. Pass it to ExternalSorting method to sort them on

```
foreach (var e in new ChoCSVReader<Customer>("Test.txt").WithDelimiter("\t").ExternalSort(new AddressCityComparer()))
    Console.WriteLine(e.City);
```

Hope this helps.